# Download CS:GO server without redownloading entire game

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, steamcmd

I'm trying to setup a home CS:GO server, but I want to do it without redownloading the entire game. I'm using Steamcmd to download the server and I've had a look at the files which it is downloading, they appear to be exactly the same as CS:GO which I already have installed. Is there anyway I can copy my current installation over so it can only download the files it needs for the dedicated server? My internet isn't very fast so letting it download will take a very long time.

Comment: The dedicated server appears to be 5191610831 bytes. Which is larger than the actual game. What is going on?

Comment: As far as I know these are two separate entities. There might be some commonalities between the games, and Steam might automatically skip those for you.

Comment: It's a huge server though. Is it really 5GB?

Comment: You understand that the dedicated server is ONLY used if you want to have your computer host a game for a long time, right? If your internet is slow that might not even be possible.

Comment: It is purely for LAN games.

Answer (score 1):

Both, the Steam client and `steamcmd` create a directory called `SteamApps` by default. Inside there's `common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive` and `common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive - Dedicated Server` respectively. The contents should be roughly the same for the game client and the dedicated server.

Copying the contents from the client to the server's directory and calling `app_update 740 validate` inside `steamcmd` (or `steamcmd +login anonymous +app_update 740 validate`) should result in a minimal download time.